# how to keep user sign in for app life?

Tags: java, android, quickblox

i'm having problem to keep the user sign in for all my app life, the "sign in" is on the main activity, when start another activity i'm still loged in and i can upload data to quickblox, but after i start another activity and then start again the activy that i uploaded data to quickblox, i get error when try to upload data: "token is required"...

Edit:

```
 QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(String.valueOf(APP_ID), AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
    QBUser user = new QBUser("login", "password");
    QBAuth.createSession(user, this, QBQueries.SIGN_IN);
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be more code? but from your question I believe you need to store the user's token and just pass it along on every single API request (that is how most API work)

Comment: The code you posted could not be less relevant. Please post the code dealing with the tokens and API requests.

Comment: if i already sing in i don't need "pass it along on every single API request"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's another issue

"token is required" means that you didn't create session and trying to perform other query

You have to properly create a session first

```
        QBAuth.createSession(new QBCallbackImpl() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Result result) {
                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    // do other requests here 
                    //
                } else {
                    handleErrors(result);
                }
            }
        });
```

If it's not an issue for you - please provide more code in your question

**UPD**

1) Try to check token for null

```
try {
    String token = BaseService.getBaseService().getToken();
    if(token == null){
        // recreate session here
    }
} catch (BaseServiceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is not my issue, i don't have problem to sign in, and it's work well, i can upload and download data without any problem, my issue is that after a while in my app (moving from activity to activity and so..) randomly it's stop working - like it's perform 'signout' by it self

Comment: Hmm, looks like token becomes null.
Try to log every time a token BaseService.getBaseService().getToken()
and check, if it's null by some reason - recreate a session

Comment: I am facing the same problem and my token is not null anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what how to use this API you are using here but if you want an alternate suggestion, I have always used `SharedPreferences` to save user sessions.

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("username", username); // Save the username with tag "username"
editor.putString("password", password); // Save the password with tag "password"
editor.commit();
```

And to get the user info back:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
u = settings.getString("username", null);
p = settings.getString("password", null);
if(u == null && p == null) {...} // No saved user session, have user sign in
else {...} // User already logged in, go to main screen
```

Comment: thanks, this is not my problem, i'm saving user details on SharedPreferences, but, in this Api, you just need to sign in one time, and on Api request you don't need to sign again, and don't need to enter user details.